# put the following in standard form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers

how do I compute the following by putting it in standad form?
\begin{equation}
(2-2\sqrt{3i})^{20}
\end{equation}

what I have tried to do is use de Moivre theorem

but that requires me to put it in polar form, as in z=...

but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: One could hope there is a typo, and that it is $2-2\sqrt{3}\,i$.

Comment: Write $2-2\sqrt 3 i=4(\frac 12-\frac{\sqrt 3}2i)$ and this is suppose to tell you something.

Comment: Just to confirm, is $i$ inside the root?

Comment: I assumed it wasn't a typo and one was required to the root or ... ah, you mean because it is ambiguous which of the square roots is meant, didn't you.

Comment: That's not the part I meant. In the post $i$ looks to be inside the square root sign. Maybe it is meant to be outside.

Comment: i is inside the root

Comment: Are you sure i is inside the root?  We can work with that but there is some ambiguity as to which of the two possible values it may be....

Comment: actually you know what...let's say the i is outside the root, just so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: using computer algebra reduce http://reduce-algebra.com/ , 
$(2-2\sqrt 3 i)^{20}=-549755813888(\sqrt{3}i+1)$ while $(2-2\sqrt{3 i})^{20}=33554432(-162846\sqrt{i}\sqrt{3}i+1111478\sqrt{i}\sqrt{3}-1161831i-1560724)$

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but try writing $\sqrt{i} =\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: I just confirmed, i is out of the root

Comment: If $i$ is outside the square root then just use Claude's comment.

Comment: I am still not sure of what "it is supposed to tell me" as Claude said. In fact can someone tell me how the answer was reached?..Claude perhaps?

Comment: @dd123 I hope if $i$ is inside the root, the answer would be $$(2-2\sqrt{3}\cdot e^\dfrac{i\pi}{4})^{20} $$ or $$(-2+(1+i)\sqrt{6})^{20}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:..................
$$i=\frac{(1+i)^2}{2}$$
$$i=-\frac{(1-i)^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $2 - 2\sqrt 3 i = 4(\frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i)$.

Now a neat thing happens when we raise $(\frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i)$ to powers.

$(\frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i)^2 = \frac 1 4 - \frac 3 4 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i = - \frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i$

So $(\frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i)^3 = (- \frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i)(\frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i) = - (\frac 1 2)^2 + (\frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i)^2 = - \frac 1 4 - \frac 3 4 = -1$

$(\frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i)^{20} = ((\frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i)^3)^6*(\frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i)^2 = 1*(- \frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i) = - \frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i$

======

So $(2 - 2\sqrt 3 i)^{20} = 4^{20}(\frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i)^{20} = 2^{40}(- \frac 1 2 - \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 i) = -2^{39}(1 + \sqrt 3 i)$

+++++++++++++++

And we all could have saved ourselves a lot of time is we recognize $(1/2, -\sqrt3 /2)$ as the height and base of a 30-60-90 triangle and thus the number is a 6th root of 1 and a cube root of -1.